# Replace strings from one array with another in Liquid

Tags: arrays, loops, shopify, liquid

I need to translate some country names to their denonyms in Liquid, but I'm having a little trouble.

I think I have the underlying logic correct here, however it is only working on products where the "country_of_origin" the last element in each array. So, at the moment a product with country of origin "Australia" will output "Australian", but the transformation doesn't happen on products from any other country.

```
{% assign countries = "France, Chile, Spain, Australia" | split: ", "%}
{% assign denonyms = "French, Chilean, Spanish, Australian" | split: ", "%}
{% assign d = countries.size | minus:1 %}
{% for i in (0..d) %}
  {% assign denonized = product.metafields.custom.country_of_origin.value | replace: countries[i],denonyms[i] %}
{% endfor %}
  {{ denonized }}
```

If anyone were to take a look here I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you reassign the variable in the loop, so only the last replacement is working.

This is your version but with a correct assignment:

```
% assign countries = "France, Chile, Spain, Australia" | split: ", "%}
{% assign denonyms = "French, Chilean, Spanish, Australian" | split: ", "%}
{% assign d = countries.size | minus:1 %}
{% assign denonized = product.metafields.custom.country_of_origin.value %}
{% for i in (0..d) %}
  {% assign denonized = denonized | replace: countries[i],denonyms[i] %}
{% endfor %}
  {{ denonized }}
```

And this is an example using `forloop` instead of another variable:

```
{% assign countries = "France, Chile, Spain, Australia" | split: ", " %}
{% assign denonyms = "French, Chilean, Spanish, Australian" | split: ", " %}
{% assign denonized = product.metafields.custom.country_of_origin.value %}
{% for country in countries %}
    {% assign denonized = replaced | replace: country, denonyms[forloop.index0] %}
{% endfor %}
{{ denonized }}
```

If you have many countries you could add a `if previous_value!=new_value break` to avoid looping for all the possible countries after you have already replaced.